# Changing CKEditor youtube plugin settings

Tags: javascript, youtube, ckeditor

I'm working website with inline [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) WYIWYG editor with the [youtube](http://ckeditor.com/addon/youtube) plugin enabled. I was wondering if it is possible to disable some of the advanced settings in the modal window that shows when you try to add a video. I would like to disable these options (entirely)

1. Embedded code - instead I would like users to be able to only insert the youtube link
2. Youtube video dimensions - due to the layout, the dimensions have to be fixed to certain width and height.

Are there any settings I'm missing which disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go in the plugin "youtube" and in the file "plugin.js" you delete what you don't.

I did like that for me.

I don't know if there is one another way.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I though I'd do too. I was hoping there was another way. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

First, I highly recommend the `Developer Tools` plugin for when you're developing your text editor.  It will tell you the names (id's) of dialog boxes, tabs and controls:

http://ckeditor.com/addon/devtools

With that installed, you can easily find out the id of any element.  Obviously, remove that plugin before pushing this into a production environment!!

Here is the code to remove the items you asked about (the last line to hide "or" above the URL requires jQuery.  You find the element with `document.getElementById(cke_67_uiElement)` to remove it, or use CSS to `display: none`.  Also, that ID is probably specific to my implementation, so use Firebug to find out the exact ID of that element.):

```
        CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev){
            // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
            var dialogName = ev.data.name;

            if (dialogName == 'youtube'){
                var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
                var youtubeTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('youtubePlugin');
                youtubeTab.remove('txtEmbed');
                youtubeTab.remove('txtWidth');
                youtubeTab.remove('txtHeight');

                //remove span with "or" inside
                $("#cke_67_uiElement").hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hiding the or did not work for me because the element is not yet rendered.  Perhaps things have changed since 2014 :)  Anyway here is what I got working for any who happen to land here:

        setTimeout(function() {
            var element = document.getElementById('cke_465_uiElement');
            if (element) {
            element.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }, 0);

Answer (score 1):

2024 solution.  This is a variation on the existing answer because for me at least the "or" element has not yet rendered so a setTimeout is needed to let it fully render before hiding it.

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev){
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;

    if (dialogName == 'youtube'){
        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
        var youtubeTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('youtubePlugin');
        youtubeTab.remove('txtEmbed');
        youtubeTab.remove('txtWidth');
        youtubeTab.remove('txtHeight');

        //wait for "or" ui element to render then hide it.
        setTimeout(function() {
            var element = document.getElementById('cke_465_uiElement');
            if (element) {
            element.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }, 0);
          
    }
});
```